# 3D numpy array changing all values situated between 2 other values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to change all the values of a 3D numpy array situated between 2 other values such as:

```
array = np.random.randint(0,256,(44,640,640))
array[array < 93 and array != 0] = 1
array[array >= 93] = 7
```

However, this syntax does not work. What is the correct way to perform this operation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. You need to fix your condition like this:

```
array = np.random.randint(0,256,(44,640,640))
array[(array < 93) & (array != 0)] = 1
array[array >= 93] = 7
```

Comment: That was so simple ! I am sorry to have ask such a pity question. I hope it helps someone else in the future tho. Thank you very mich Ehsan !

Comment: @Unic0 Glad it helped :)